# Highcharts save a chart in the project folder instead of downloads folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I need to generate an svg for a chart with a pattern. I have added images using the pattern fill plugin.

```
                    name : 'XXX',
                    id : 'Series 3',
                    type : 'column',   
                    data : [ protected_protection_ng_values ],
                    color :
                    {
                            pattern : './image-assets/pattern1.png',
                            width : 190,
                            height : 190
                    }
```

But when i generate the svg images, the pattern images don't appear because the svg is looking for the images in the downloads folder. How can I save the svg in a folder in my project using only javascript (any other method other than  PhantomJS script. If that is the best solution please enlighten on how to do it)?

Comment: Will the SVG be viewed offline? Why not use an absolute path to a online location?

Comment: It is viewed offline because the clients needs an svg format image which has to be added to the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

When using [Pattern Fill](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/9/Pattern-Fill) plugin in version 2 you can define patterns as `SVG` elements and they will be exported without the need to refer to any outside image files.

See the custom patter demo with exporting enabled: http://jsfiddle.net/fzL82mnw/

Other option could be to use base64 instead of url for a pattern. To see how base64 images are embedded in exported SVG you could export [boost module demo](http://www.highcharts.com/articles/2-news/175-highcharts-performance-boost) charts and exterminate output SVG.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/studies/canvas-area/